# Change span class color

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been trying to change my span class color to red without any success. It'll strike it through. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

This is the website link:
https://qcba.cloudaccess.host/

Im trying to change NBA color to red
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `!important` to the color value.